# Using step definition with status undefined in Karate Testing

Tags: cucumber, karate

I need to used a step that returns undefined status in html cucumber report.
Which keyword can be use?

My version is:
com.intuit.karate
karate-apache
0.9.5
test

Thanks

Comment: Karate is *NOT* Cucumber. Can you explain what you mean by an example or a link to some web-page ? Else please assume that this is not supported by Karate and you can look for another tool.

Comment: I know that Karate is not Cucumber, but it uses the same logic behind it.
We need to create features that are marked in the report cucumber as not implemented. Any ideas?

Comment: `same logic` ? nope :) https://hackernoon.com/yes-karate-is-not-true-bdd-698bf4a9be39

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you want is the [`karate.abort()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-abort) syntax.

Or you can just put a `* print 'this is not implemented yet'`

And / or use a tag: https://github.com/intuit/karate#tags

In my opinion, that is more that enough to solve for what you need. If not, you can consider contributing code to Karate, it is open-source.